# How to adjust the size of UITextField.leftView?

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I am trying to change adjust the size of the a UIImageView that is the leftView of my UITextField without any success.  The image is always huge.  I would like it to have the same height as my UITextField.  Here is what i have tried:

Result:

[image]

```
let topContainer: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.appGrayExtraLightGray.cgColor
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

let emailField: UITextField = {
    let view = UITextField()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    view.text = "myEmailAddress@gmail.com"
    view.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

let s = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

    topContainer.addSubview(emailField)
    emailField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainer.topAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
    emailField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
    emailField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -spacing).isActive = true
    emailField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: -spacing).isActive = true

    /**Mail and clear button on eitherisde of textField*/
    let mailView = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 15, height: 15)) // Chaning the GREct has no effect on the size!!
    mailView.image = UIImage.init(named: "mailGrayFilled")
    emailField.leftView = mailView
    emailField.leftViewMode = .always
    emailField.clearButtonMode = .always

    view.addSubview(topContainer)
    topContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: s.topAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
    topContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: s.leadingAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
    topContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: s.trailingAnchor, constant: -spacing).isActive = true
```

Comment: `mailView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit` ?

Comment: @rbaldwin No effect. same result as above.  I have also tried replacing the UIImageView with a button and set the backgroundImage to the same image and i get the same resut.

Comment: Add the icon imageView in container view. Here is a good resource for this: https://medium.com/nyc-design/swift-4-add-icon-to-uitextfield-48f5ebf60aa1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the `UIImageView` into a Container `UIView` seems to fix the issue when I test your code.  This may also allow you to adjust the padding to suit your needs.

```
let iconContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 15))
let mailView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 15, height: 15))
mailView.image = UIImage(named: "mailGrayFilled")
mailView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
iconContainer.addSubview(mailView)
emailField.leftViewMode = .always
emailField.leftView = iconContainer
emailField.clearButtonMode = .always
```